# Why Invalid conversion requested ERROR CODE: 17132?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to get last inserted row id while inserting using JDBC prepared statements. I have an auto increment primary key column as identity column in table. My code is below:

```
public static String insertMeetingToDB(String organizer,String subject,String location,String start_date_time,String end_date_time,String description) throws Exception {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    Integer last_inserted_id=0;


String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO MEETINGS"
                   + "(ORGANIZER_EMAIL, SUBJECT, MEETING_LOCATION, START_DATE_TIME, END_DATE_TIME, MEETING_DESCRIPTION) VALUES"
                   + "(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
from.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));  //--CONVERTING DATE/TIME TO INDIAN STANDARD TIME

SimpleDateFormat datetimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");

Date input_start_date_val =  from.parse(start_date_time);
Date input_end_date_val =  from.parse(end_date_time);

String input_start_date =  datetimeFormat.format(input_start_date_val);
String input_end_date =  datetimeFormat.format(input_end_date_val);

try {

        dbConnection = getConnection();

        //--INSERTING MEETING DETAILS
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL, preparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        preparedStatement.setString(1, organizer);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, subject); 
        preparedStatement.setString(3, location);
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(input_start_date));
        preparedStatement.setTimestamp(5, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(input_end_date));
        preparedStatement.setString(6, description);

        // execute insert SQL stetement
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            last_inserted_id = rs.getInt(1);
        }

        return last_inserted_id.toString();

} catch (SQLException e) {
        return e.getMessage()+" ERROR CODE: "+e.getErrorCode();
} finally {
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
                dbConnection = null; 
        }
  }
}
```

If I delete this line then I didn't got this error:

```
last_inserted_id = rs.getInt(1);
```

But after googleing it seems to be ok with this code, which should return me last inserted row id.

Table Description:

```
CREATE TABLE MEETINGS (
  MEETING_ID  NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  ORGANIZER_EMAIL VARCHAR2(100),
  SUBJECT VARCHAR2(250),
  START_DATE_TIME TIMESTAMP,
  END_DATE_TIME TIMESTAMP,
  ATTENDEES_LIST_CONFIDENTIAL CHAR(1),
  ATTENDEES_CONF_CONFIDENTIAL CHAR(1),
  ATTENDEES_COUNT_INTERNAL NUMBER(11),
  ATTENDEES_COUNT_EXTERNAL NUMBER(11),
  CONFIRMED_COUNT_INTERNAL NUMBER(11),
  CONFIRMED_COUNT_EXTERNAL NUMBER(11),
  PREVIOUS_MEETING_ID NUMBER(20),
  APPOINTMENT_SOURCE CHAR(1),
  MEETING_LOCATION VARCHAR(100),
  LATITUDE FLOAT(10),
  LONGITUDE FLOAT(10),
  MEETING_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(1000),
  PRIMARY KEY(MEETING_ID)
);
```

Comment: Can you post the table description (DDL) and the full error message?

Comment: Added table description, full error message is given in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Oracle JDBC documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/jdbcvers.htm#CHDEGDHJ) says:

> If key columns are not explicitly indicated, then Oracle JDBC drivers cannot identify which columns need to be retrieved. When a column name or column index array is used, Oracle JDBC drivers can identify which columns contain auto-generated keys that you want to retrieve. However, when the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` integer flag is used, Oracle JDBC drivers cannot identify these columns. When the integer flag is used to indicate that auto-generated keys are to be returned, the `ROWID` pseudo column is returned as key. The `ROWID` can be then fetched from the `ResultSet` object and can be used to retrieve other columns.

You aren't specifying the columns (as shown in their sample code) so you're retrieving the `ROWID`; trying to get that with `getInt()` is causing the error you see. (I actually see `Invalid column type: getInt not implemented for class oracle.jdbc.driver.RowidAccessor ERROR CODE: 17004` but I think that's down to a different driver version).

You need to specify the column that gets the auto-generated value. If it is called `MEETING_ID` then you'd do:

```
    String returnCols[] = { "MEETING_ID" };
    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL, returnCols);
```

... passing the array of columns - only one in this case - rather than the RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS flag.

The `rs.getInt(1)` will then be retrieving that numeric value.

Comment: Worth to note this is not the case for other DB types, like PSQL. There, `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` works while explicitly indicating the columns does not.