# JDBC :how generate primary keys automatically and insert it into database

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

i have a table like this,

create table ruff(id varchar(25) primary key,name varchar(30));

i need to insert primary keys for ids automatically from jdbc help please?

Comment: It's explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733085/auto-increment-for-oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC doesn't generate ids automatically. It's usually the database that does it, but even the database wouldn't generate one for `VARCHAR(25)` without using triggers.

For retrieving the database generated keys you can use `con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);`, although that probably doesn't work with trigger generated values.

Comment: You can [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32114047/266304) to retrieve the keys, even if they are generated by a trigger. However you'd do that for a string key...

Comment: For Oracle you can use `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` you just need to be prepared to handle the fact that it doesn't return the generated id, but the `ROWID`, which can then be used to query for the row to get the actual generated id.

Answer (score 0):

Define a Sequence in Oracle and in yur insert statement under values clause fill your ID with sequence.nextval
Eg- 
insert into ruff(id,name)
values(your_sequence.nextval,'name')

Answer (score 0):

You can define the Sequence in Oracle database and also specify the custom generation methods for Sequences. And when you are inserting on the values into the table, rather than providing the values from the user, you can use the previously generated Sequence so as to insert the Primary key.