# How to use a RowId returned from PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, rowid

I have the code below. It's a prepared statement with a request to return the generated keys.

In the generatedKeys result set, the only return column is named "ROWID" and value is an instance of the `RowId` class. See screencap at the bottom.

My question is **how to use the row id to get the whole row?**

```
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insert, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
SqlUtils.addParams(preparedStatement, params);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
ResultSet generatedKeys = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
```

[image]

Comment: Did you look at Oracle's documentation [Using RowId Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlrowid.html)?

Comment: Not directly answering the question, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32114047/266304) might be slightly relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Once I inserted the data, and got the `rowid`, I can use it to [super fastly](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) extract the whole row, including the generated values that were inserted, for example values inserted by a DB procedure.

Example of using the rowid to extract the row:

```
Object rowId = generatedKeys.getObject(1);
String tableName = generatedKeys.getMetaData().getTableName(1);
List<Map<String, Object>> resAsList = select(conn, "select * from " + tableName + " where rowid=?", rowId);
```