# Nifi invalid conversion requested

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to load csv file into oracle db using GetFile and PutDatabaseRecord processors using apache nifi

Able to read the csv file but unable to insert because of below error in the putdatabaserecord

Invalid conversion requested. Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: The table you are trying to insert has any datetime column? Also can you please post the PutDatabaseRecord properties screenshot?

Comment: Have a look at this as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112907/why-invalid-conversion-requested-error-code-17132